# Import html to rails method (in helper.rb)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need piece of code for couple of times, and to follow DRY method (don't repeat yourself) i want to escape using this piece and retyping it for 5 times or more. So I want to define method what will contain both ruby and html, and ruby in html and js to, code. But I have problems with realization.

My html.erb look like this:

```
<% div_count = 1 %>
<div>
  <% for post in @posts %>
    <div class="post-on-main-page-<%= div_count %>"
         id="js-count-<%= div_count_for_js %>">
      <script>
        $("#js-count-<%= div_count_for_js %>").click(function(){
          window.location.href = "<%= post_url(post) %>";
        });
      </script>
    <%= image_tag(post.picture.url) %>
    <span><h5><%= post.theme %></h5></span>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% div_count += 1 %>
<% if div_count == 4 %>
  <% div_count = 1 %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

And I want create method, I think in application_helper.rb will do with this piece of code. What will look something like that:

```
def method_name(parameter)
<% div_count = 1 %>
    <div>
      <% for post in parameter %>
        <div class="post-on-main-page-<%= div_count %>"
             id="js-count-<%= div_count_for_js %>">
          <script>
            $("#js-count-<%= div_count_for_js %>").click(function(){
              window.location.href = "<%= post_url(post) %>";
            });
          </script>
          <%= image_tag(post.picture.url) %>
          <span><h5><%= post.theme %></h5></span>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% div_count += 1 %>
    <% if div_count == 4 %>
      <% div_count = 1 %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
end
```

The result what I want for html.erb

```
<%= method_name(@posts)%>
```

How can I make this to work?

Comment: use partials http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 0):

You can move this code to some html. And when you want to use it, you just call render method.

```
<%= render 'html_file' %>
```

Comment: Yes, but @posts variable will be changed on different pages, and I want to avoid copy pasting code for 5 or 6 time. And if I want to change something on one page, it must be changed on every page. So what you recommend will not work for me.

Comment: You could try to do smth like this: 
`def method_name(params); @posts = params; render 'html_file'; end`